# Date Time Encoding

Tags: c#, .net

Any ideas or implementations floating about for encoding the current date including the milliseconds into the shortest possible string length?

e.g I want 31/10/2011 10:41:45 in the shortest string possible (ideally 5 characters) - obviously decodable.

If it is impossible to get down to 5 characters, then the year is optional.

edit: it doesn't actually need to be decodable. It just needs to be a unique string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ASCII characters to represent the numbers and drop the formatting, for example:

```
31/10/2011 10:41:45

*/*/** *:*:*

*******
```

That's 7, you can drop 2 if you don't want to include the full year. Obviously the * are actual characters relating to a number, A could be 1 etc, or even use the proper ASCII codes.

Comment: I think this looks quite tasty.

Answer (score 5):

An `time_t` is 31 bits. Add 10 bits for up to 1000 milliseconds: That's 41 bits. You want 5 characters: That's 8 bits for the 1st 4 characters + 9 bits for the last one.
Using Chinese ideograms, you should easily be able to find a range of 256 consecutive chars for each of the 1st 4 chars and a range of 512 for the last one.

Needless to say your encoded date will look... chinese! But it should do the trick ;-)

BTW, you don't have to stick to Chinese. You might even want to choose a different Unicode 256 chars range for each character. Of course, you'll want to find sequences of 256/512 *printable* chars.

Now let's say we skip the year. We're down to 86400 x 366 seconds per year = 31622400 seconds. Including millisecs : 31622400000. That's 35 bits. Great: We're down at 7 bits per character. Easy! :-)

Comment: I'll give a +1 because your response is funny :-)

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx):

```
var ticks = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks;
```

this is a 64bit number. You get the Time back by calling:

```
var timeBack = new System.DateTime(ticks);
```

of course this are 8 bytes but I don't think you can get this more compact (easily).

Comment: Ticks will not be around five characters.

Comment: I don't read this as a LIMIT - ("ideally") - you know a better way? Post it!

Comment: Yeah the limit is important but I was welcoming of all suggestions. This is useful but probably not ideal. thanks for your contribution Carsten

Answer (score 2):

No can do: The total ms in an year (365 days) is 31,536,000,000 (=365*24*60*60*1000). You need 34.87628063 bits of information to store that value (log2 31,536,000,000). You probably meant "printable characters" BUT you would need 7 bits/character to store 35 bits in 5 characters. As an example base64 is 6 bits/character of information, so 6 characters. [Ascii85](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85) would be a little better, but still you would need around 5.5 characters, so 6 characters.

Clearly if you meant 5 BYTES, everything changes. You can store 34.84 years (in ms) in that space.

And if you meant 5 C# PRINTABLE AND UNPRINTABLE CHARACTERS (each C# character is 16 bits), then it's even better. 10 bytes! `DateTime` in C# is only 8 bytes and it uses ticks (they are a VERY VERY VERY small part of a second)!

BUT if you meant 5 C# PRINTABLE CHARACTERS characters, then use Serge's response. It's very good and show us that the world is a big place (and show us that why good questions are so much important: they let us see the world in new ways).

Comment: Welcome to the world of Unicode, where characters are no longer only latin letters ;-)

Comment: @Serge If you want to play with other rules, you are free :-) In the end a character is a character, even if it isn't printable. So a character on a PC is at least 8 bytes. You don't even need Unicode :-) (yes, \0 is a character :-) ). If you don't trust me, ask a Linux expert how filenames are saved: agnostically. Every character save the \0 and two or three others are saved "as is".

Comment: The question is tagged .NET. A character is therefore a UTF16 character. It can hold more than 8 bits. Therefore I don't agree with your "no can do". BTW, thanks for your upvote ;-)

Comment: +1 OP's question only makes sense if he/she meant *bytes* instead of characters. Using 5 non printable UTF16 characters to store a DateTime is nonsense, it would be simpler to use Ticks instead, so I doubt this is what OP had in mind.

Comment: @Serge I'm not very sure if a Char in .NET is UTF-16 or UCS-2. I would say it is a 16bit unsigned value that some methods use in some ways and others in other ways. Not all the .NET API is UTF-16 (`Regex` for example)

Comment: @xanatos: `char`'s UTF-16, pretty sure of it. EDIT: [Yep.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx)

Comment: @Groo: OP clearly mentions strings and characters, not bytes. Why is it nonsense to encode some data into a string? After, we do it all of the time. And why should we stick to ASCII?

Comment: @Chris But string.Length is in characters for example, and there aren't many functions that throw on invalid UTF-16 couples. MSDN tells us: .NET Framework uses the Char structure to represent a Unicode character. The Unicode Std identifies each U. character with a unique 21-bit scalar number called a code point, and defines the UTF-16 encoding form that specifies how a code point is encoded into a sequence of one or more 16-bit values. Each 16-bit value ranges from hex 0x0000 through 0xFFFF and is stored in a Char struct. The value of a Char obj. is its 16-bit numeric (ordinal) value.

Comment: @xanatos: Then it's quicksand, and the only real way of figuring out how things'll work is by experimentation. MSDN's been divorced from reality before.

Comment: @Serge I'll forward you thoughts to the ones that invented Base64 and Ascii85 :-) I'm completely favorable on killing legacy systems that don't support full Unicode 6.0 that introduced the very important `emoji`.

Comment: @Serge: It's nonsense for two reasons: 1. 5xUTF16 chars take 10bytes, which is two bytes **larger** than 8 bytes (8 bytes are sufficient to store a 64-bit DateTime in **100ns ticks**, not just milliseconds), and 2. if a character in non-printable, then it actually less useful to a user than a number. What OP wants is either: a) to encode time into **bytes** in order to serialize it, or b) to make a shorter **readable** representation (like online url shorteners do). What you are proposing is longer, not readable, and still a sequence of bytes underneath: I would not suggest it as a solution.

Comment: @Groo No, his idea IS very good. It's lateral thinking. It's like codifying a DateTime in a 2D bar code. Clearly you can't read it directly, but if you need to print it and then scan for it, then it's a good idea. For this reason I gave him a +1.

Comment: @xanatos: I would say the opposite: encoding DateTime to a **number** is like converting it to a bar code (easy to save on a computer, easy to serialize, easy to deserialize, easy to print and scan as a barcode). Encoding DateTime to Chinese characters only obfuscates the data: it is harder even for a user to write it down, it cannot be serialized/deserialized prior to converting to a number, and the printing/scanning part compared to scanning a barcode (which is a **number**) means using OCR for **Chinese**? Only to store a 64-bit number? If you have a useful reason for that, please say it.

Comment: @Groo: characters and bytes are not the same thing. Period. Either we speak of characters (and strings) or we speak of bytes or other raw computer-related storage. The fact that characters are stored in a computer using bytes is only due to the nature of computers and is an implementation detail. In a printed book, characters are not represented by bytes. That said, you are right that we don't need 5 characters to pack the date/time info. We could probably do it with 3 characters. It's more complicated because we won't find large enough contiguous ranges. But yes, it can be done.

Comment: @xanatos: :-D I suggest we rephrase the question: How many emoji do you need to represent a unique moment in time? Nobel prize anyone? :-)

Comment: @Serge There are 722 "recognized" emoji, but they are split all around the unicode... So 9.495855027 bits/emoji :-)